How does Python create values for variables without assignment?
I am reading Engineering a Compiler (Cooper, Torczon) 3rd Edition, Chapter 5 Syntax-Driven Translation. It contains the paragraph:

PYTHON does not provide type declarations. The first use of a name x in
a scope is its defining occurrence. If the first use assigns x a value, then it
binds x to a new local entity with its type defined by the assigned value. If
the first use refers to x’s value, then it binds x to a global entity; if no such
entity exists, then that defining use creates the entity. If the programmer
intends x to be global but needs to define it before using it, the programmer
can add a nonlocal declaration for the name, which ensures that x is in the
global scope.

How exactly can an entity be created for an undefined variable? I would think that this would result in a NameError. Can somebody please explain what the bolded clause is referring to and please provide a simple example and explain how this is different from assigning a value to an extant global variable or a new local variable?

I think that the statement is incorrect. Inside a function, whether a variable is local to the function or global to the module is defined at compile time. If the variable is assigned a value anywhere in the function body, that variable is placed in the function local scope. The compiler replaces the variable name with an index into the function's local variable list. If you don;t want the compiler to do this, you can use global and nonlocal to control how that assignment is handled. If the variable is only referenced and not assigned, python will look back throuth the containing scopes.

But it is correct in terms of a variable assigned at module level or assigned in a function when it is also marked global in that function. In that case, the variable will be created at module level if it doesn't yet exist. nonlocal is a bit stranger. The variable must be defined in the containing scope - it will not be created automatically.

In my experience, python does not have type declarations, except for type hinting. Variables can change type whenever it wants. Just think of a variable in python as a mystery box without any knowledge of what its attributes are.
